# Jmeter listner results export after script run

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

I know that we can export/save results of a listner in csv or xml format.

But what i want is to save the listner result once the script has been run.

There seems to be no way of doing this. currently giving a file path in a listner will work only before the execution begins not after it is over.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) guide it is recommended:

1. To use non-GUI mode for tests execution
2. To disable all the listeners during the test run
3. On test completion you should be able to open .jtl results file by the listener of your choice.

If you need to store some specific data required by this or that listener, take a look into *jmeter.properties* file (lives in /bin folder of your JMeter installation) and amend properties having "jmeter.save.saveservice." prefix according to your plans.

Perhaps [Automatically generating nice graphs at end of your Load Test with Apache JMeter and JMeter-Plugins](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/) guide can also help.